# Concatenate two columns within a single table

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql.

This is my table structure

Test

```
id |   A    |B    |
1  |   11   |     |
2  |   12   |     |
3  |   13   |     |
4  |   14   |abc  |
```

I want to concatenate column A and column B and get output like below

```
id |   C   |
1  |   11  |
2  |   12  |
3  |   13  |
4  |   abc |
```

My question is,is it possible to get such output in mysql?

Comment: I used coalesce() function but B column in test table contains empty values.so i get following output


id| C |
1 |   |
2 |   |
3 |   |
4 |abc|


SELECT ID, IFNULL(B,A) AS C FROM Test also produces the same result

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks basic research

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `coalesce()` function:

```
select id, coalesce(B, A) as C
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE (B, A) AS C
FROM yourtable
```

`coalesce()` evalutes arguments left->right, and returns the first non-null value.

Comment: i used coalesce() function but B column in test table contains empty values.so i get following output

Comment: coalesce works on sql NULLs. if you've got empty strings and not nulls, then coalesce won't work. `''` is NOT the same as `NULL`. you'd need something more like `IF(B = '', A, B) AS C` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, IFNULL(B,A) AS C FROM Test
```